# Is there a programming interface / web service for getting Amber Alert information?

Tags: web-services, api

I'd like to programmatically gather information about [Amber Alerts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMBER_Alert) and display it in an application. However, I can't seem to find an API. Does one exist?

I care about NJ but the entire country would be useful too.

Comment: The API exists, but I don't think it's publicly available.

Comment: Someone already did it. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.missingkids.app&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5taXNzaW5na2lkcy5hcHAiXQ..

Comment: "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: Is anyone successful in finding an API? This question was asked in 2011, I hope there is some sort of API or RSS feed that we can get the amber alerts from. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following site to retrieve an RSS feed that you could probably disseminate for the data you want. Not a perfect "API" per se, but it should work! This is NOT the official Amber Alert feed, but rather a Missing Children alert from the Nation Center for Missing and Exploited Children

http://missingkids.com/missingkids/servlet/PageServlet?LanguageCountry=en_US&PageId=1790

Comment: The issue with this of course is if the data format changes, etc. There's no guarantees here.

Comment: Absolutely...I wasn't sure what exactly you were trying to achieve, but it seems to be the best thing available as far as I could find.

Comment: You can also use the search api. This is the url for every record in their database. `https://api.missingkids.org/missingkids/servlet/JSONDataServlet?action=publicSearch&goToPage=1`

Answer (score 0):

The http://www.missingkidsbot.org project wraps up the RSS feed from http://www.missingkids.org into a Hypermedia API, http://www.missingkidsbot.org/api, https://github.com/dblock/slack-amber-alert.