# Is there an up-to-date, working Amber Alert API or a way to pull Amber Alerts to a website?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rss

I am working on a charity's website that focuses on Human Trafficking. Because this is a new chartity, they tried to find someone to do the site for free; AKA me.

---

**I need to be able to pull amber alerts to the website as they are posted. I have found a working RSS feed, but have no clue how to pull information from the RSS and have it display on my own website. My code that I have right now, is only what was in the API that I linked below**

Missing child post example: http://www.missingkids.com/poster/NCMC/1317360/1/screen

link to missing child pic: https://api.missingkids.org/photographs/NCMC1317360c1.jpg

RSS Feed for MI: http://www.missingkids.com/missingkids/servlet/XmlServlet?act=rss&LanguageCountry=en_US&orgPrefix=NCMC&state=MI

API I found, but cannot get the PHP version working. (https://github.com/katzgrau/amber-alert-api)

---

Old post that I found on Stack Overflow, but the links are no longer working. ([Is there a programming interface / web service for getting Amber Alert information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807280/is-there-a-programming-interface-web-service-for-getting-amber-alert-informati))

*Sorry this is all over the place. I don't have a lot of experience with Stack Overflow.*

Answer (score 0):

Contact the Center for Missing and Exploited Children. They post the Amber Alerts.

They should be helpful and supply the needed code.

Mark Young
Jimmy Ryce Center
954-790-9889

Comment: This appears not to be spam, but in response to the PO's question. It provides a way to contact the website for help on their API, as the published API's are outdated.